# How to unpack *.cab file via CMD?

Tags: cmd, cab

I want to extract contents of a *.cab archive using CMD. Here's my code:

```
EXPAND C:\Source\data1.cab -F:* D:\Destination
```

As a result I get a copy of data1.cab in D:\Destination. What's wrong?

Comment: What is the output of `EXPAND -D C:\Source\data1.cab`? Have you tried `EXPALL.BAT`? https://jeffpar.github.io/kbarchive/kb/074/Q74217/

Comment: @lit the output is `c:\source\data1.cab: data1.cab`. Custom batch file is not an option because I need to execute this command from installer.

Comment: It appears that the `data1.cab` contains `data1.cab`. What is the output of `EXPAND -D D:\Destination\data1.cab`?

Comment: Well, Universal Extractor unpacks initial data1.cab archive as a bunch of files, not as another data1.cab. It seems that EXPAND just doesn't work.